# Downloading with vbscript, some files not complete

Tags: file, vbscript, download

I'm using the following vbscript to automate the download of an app from my site:

```
HTTPDownload "bleh.com/hello.exe", "C:\"
HTTPDownload "bleh.com/hello1.dll", "C:\"
HTTPDownload "bleh.com/hello2.dll", "C:\"
HTTPDownload "bleh.com/hello3.dll", "C:\"

Sub HTTPDownload( myURL, myPath )
    Dim i, objFile, objFSO, objHTTP, strFile, strMsg
    Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
    Set objFSO = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
    If objFSO.FolderExists( myPath ) Then
        strFile = objFSO.BuildPath( myPath, Mid( myURL, InStrRev( myURL, "/" ) + 1 ) )
    ElseIf objFSO.FolderExists( Left( myPath, InStrRev( myPath, "\" ) - 1 ) ) Then
        strFile = myPath
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile( strFile, ForWriting, True )
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject( "WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1" )
    objHTTP.Open "GET", myURL, False
    objHTTP.Send
    For i = 1 To LenB( objHTTP.ResponseBody )
        objFile.Write Chr( AscB( MidB( objHTTP.ResponseBody, i, 1 ) ) )
    Next
    objFile.Close( )
End Sub
```

Weirdly, when I run the script, 2/4 files are downloaded fully. One of the other files is only 2 KB (should be about 180kb full) and the other one is 0 KB (200kb full).

I double checked on the ftp server, the files stored their are 100% complete and downloading them manually via the browser works fine.

Why would my script fail to fully download all four files?

Answer (score 0):

Try with an [`XMLHTTPRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh453379) instead of a [`WinHttpRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and use an [ADO stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for saving the (binary) files:

```
Sub HTTPDownload(url, path)
  Set req = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
  req.open "GET", url, False
  req.send

  If req.Status = 200 Then
    Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    stream.Open
    stream.Type = 1 'binary
    stream.Write req.responseBody
    stream.SaveToFile path
    stream.Close
  Else
    WScript.Echo req.status & " " & req.statusText
  End If
End Sub
```

The request status may give you some pointers about issues. Also check the server log (if possible).

Comment: I get a "Write to file failed." in Windows 8 when I try that. Even though I'm admin and it's not a protected directory.

Comment: Does the file already exist? If so, you need to use `stream.SaveToFile path, 2` (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms676745(v=vs.85).aspx)).