# How to rename a download file in client side programmatically?

Tags: html, vbscript

I hope to download a file (such as http://www.example.com/my.zip) and rename it (such as rename my.zip to newfile.zip) when I save it to local disk.

I hope to write a code to do it, I don't know if VBScript can do it, or HTML can do it.

BTW, the following code doesn't work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title>HTML5 download Attribute Example</title>
</head>

<body>
<a href="https://ams-nl-ping.vultr.com/vultr.com.100MB.bin"
    download="newfile.zip">Download Your Expense Report</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Neither of those languages can automatically rename a file for you. Why not simply call the file what you want it to be downloaded as on the server (www.example.com/newfile.zip)?

Comment: Thanks! What I need download isn't in  my server

Comment: Can the save file dialog of a web browser fill in a new file name using code?

Comment: I have read https://davidwalsh.name/download-attribute ,and place a download attribute on a link..

Comment: But   <a href="https://ams-nl-ping.vultr.com/vultr.com.100MB.bin" download="my.zip">Download Your Expense Report</a>  don't work

Comment: Remove the semicolon.

Comment: Thanks! I get the same result after I remove the semicolon.  BTW  the semicolon is added by stackoverflow.

Comment: Don't try to automate the GUI. Download and save the file directly with VBScript. [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20103315/1630171).

Comment: To Ansgar Wiechers: Could you show me some sample code? Thanks!

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers the `X-UA-Compatible` flag on the HTML is set to `IE=Edge` so client-side VBScript will be unavailable.

Comment: @HelloCW Did you bother following the link in my comment?

Comment: @Lankymart My suggestion did not involve any browser.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers is running it from a website, not a requirement?, I guess if not, that will work.

Comment: HTML isn't a scripting language. The HTML example here is misleading. I suggest removing it.

Comment: Try to follow the link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10049259/change-name-of-download-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work without a HTML file *(if that isn't a requirement)*, have tested it and it produces a 100MB zip file in `C:\temp` called `newfile.zip`.

Just remember when you execute the command, do so in an elevated context.

```
cscript //nologo "myscript.vbs"
```

Code `myscript.vbs`

```
Option Explicit

Const adTypeBinary = 1
Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2

Call main()

Sub main()
  Dim url: url = "https://ams-nl-ping.vultr.com/vultr.com.100MB.bin"
  Dim path: path = "c:\temp\newfile.zip"
  Dim resp: resp = downloadFromURL(url)
  If Not IsEmpty(resp) Then
    Call SaveStreamToFile(resp, path)
  Else
    Call WScript.Echo("Failed to download from " & url)
  End If
End Sub

Function downloadFromURL(url)
  Dim http: Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
  Dim stream

  Call http.Open("GET", url, False)
  Call http.Send()

  If http.Status = 200 Then
    downloadFromURL = http.responseBody
  Else
    downloadFromURL = Empty
  End If
End Function

Sub SaveStreamToFile(resp, path)
    Dim stream: Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    With stream
      Call .Open()
      .Type = adTypeBinary
      Call .Write(resp)
      Call .SaveToFile(path, adSaveCreateOverWrite)
      Call .Close()
    End With
End Sub
```

There are lots of ways this could be improved, at the moment the variables `url` and `path` are hardcoded but could be passed in using the `WScript.Arguments` collection, allowing you to pass the values as parameters of the script on the command line. Could also improve the error handling passing back the `StatusText` from HTTP request, but will leave this to you.

This is simply a bare bones example, intended to be built on.

Comment: Thanks! but your code doesn't work!

I have created the folder c:\temp ,and create the file myscript.vbs on c:\ 

After I run cscript //nologo "c:\myscript.vbs" on Windows Command prompt, the system display only a Command windows ,just like 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cw6vefvizbp6pja/Download.PNG?dl=0

Comment: newfile.zip doesn't be created on c:\temp